# escape all child with CData in C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, xml

I have a question, 'How to convert JSON to XML and store it to an sql database'. 
I'm already capable of converting json to xml using the following:

```
XmlDocument xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json, "root");
```

However, when I store data to the sql server I receive an error because of an unescaped character.

This is a sample of my converted xml:

```
<root>
    <collage>
        <name>SIGMA INSTITUTE</name>
        <students>650</students>
        <url>http://www.test.com</url>
    </collage>
    <collage>
        <name>ORCHID INSTITUTE</name>
        <students>1200</students>
        <url>http://www.test.com</url>
    </collage>
</root>
```

I think it occurs because it's an unescaped character in xml, but I don't know how to escape the character.

Comment: The xml you posted is good and shouldn't give any errors.  When you are storing data to a database make sure you are using a parameter.  If you don't use a parameter the drive has to guess the type of data and often  wil guess wrong and give errors.  It is similar to using General Formatting in an Excel spreadsheet and the spread sheet converting integers to dates or dates to integers.

Comment: cools that working thanks for your help